# string concatenation - TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Tags: python, string, typeerror, unary-operator, operands

I'm trying to write the output of some fit algorithm to a text log file:

```
with open(outputPath + 'fit_logfile.txt', mode='a') as fit_logfile:
    fit_logfile.write('\n'
                        + inputPath + filename + ':\n'
                        + 'Initial parameters:\n',
                        + 'x0_init = ' + str(params_init[0]) + '\n'
                        + 'y0_init = ' + str(params_init[1]) + '\n'
                        + 'Imax_init = ' + str(params_init[2]) + '\n'
                        + 'FHWM_init = ' + str(params_init[3]) + '\n'
                        + 'Optimized parameters:\n'
                        + 'x0_opt = ' + str(params_opt[0]) + '\n'
                        + 'y0_opt = ' + str(params_opt[1]) + '\n'
                        + 'Imax_opt = ' + str(params_opt[2]) + '\n'
                        + 'FHWM_opt = ' + str(params_opt[3]) + '\n'
                        + 'Standard deviations:\n'
                        + 'sigma_x0 = ' + str(params_err[0]) + '\n'
                        + 'sigma_y0 = ' + str(params_err[1]) + '\n'
                        + 'sigma_Imax = ' + str(params_err[2]) + '\n'
                        + 'sigma_FWHM = ' + str(params_err[3]) + '\n')
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-9d3a854ada12> in <module>()
     54                             + 'sigma_y0 = ' + str(params_opt[1]) + '\n'
     55                             + 'sigma_Imax = ' + str(params_opt[2]) + '\n'
---> 56                             + 'sigma_FWHM = ' + str(params_opt[3]) + '\n')
     57
     58

TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Get rid of the comma after `'Initial parameters:\n'`

Comment: @alaniwi: Oh nooo... xD  Thank you!!

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker: Thanks, I read that thread, but it's just a comma I forgot to delete

Comment: @frankmertens So the point is, it was complaining about **unary** `+`, (e.g. as might occur in a constant like `+1` rather being used as an addition operator), so it was a case of looking to see where you might have a `+` that wasn't preceded by an operand.

Comment: Yes, the error message is actually instructive (but it doesn't prevent user error ^^)